# SugarORM: SugarRecord.count returns 4 but SugarRecord.listAll returns empty list

Tags: android, sugarorm

I use the `@Table` annotation for my model and call `SugarRecord.save` in a `DialogFragment.setPositiveButton.onClick`

In the Fragment with the ListView I wanted to load all entries via `SugarRecord.listAll` but it returns an empty list, although `SugarRecord.count` returns the proper count.

## My Code

### Syllable.java

```
@Table
@ToString
@Getter
public class Syllable {

    private Long id;

    @Unique
    String characters;
    @Setter
    boolean active = true;

    public Syllable(String characters) {
        this.characters = characters;
    }
}
```

### DialogFragment.setPositiveButton

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        SugarRecord.save(new Syllable(charactersET.getText().toString()));
                        syllableDialogListener.onSyllableSave();
                    }
                })
```

### Fragment.onSyllableSave

```
private void updateSyllables() {
        long count = SugarRecord.count(Syllable.class); // returns 4 (e.g.)
        List<Syllable> syllables = SugarRecord.listAll(Syllable.class); // returns empty list
    }
```

Comment: share your code. for reference http://codex2android.blogspot.in/2016/03/sugar-orm-sqlite-android-part-2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I was just missing an empty constructor at the model >_> Problem was this wasn't really printed as an red-error-style error in android studio so I just missed this ;D