# Sugar ORM listAll() not showing any data

Tags: android, android-database, sugarorm

I'm trying to get data from databse in a listview as shown below.

```
  long count = UserTableSugar.count(UserTableSugar.class);
    if(count>0)
    {
        UserTableSugar.listAll(UserTableSugar.class);
        List<UserTableSugar> userTable = UserTableSugar.listAll(UserTableSugar.class);
        CustomAdapterListview madapter = new CustomAdapterListview(getApplicationContext(),userTable);
        listView.setAdapter(madapter);
    }
```

but,the data won't show up. On debugging, the value of *count* is 2 (there are two records in table). But the size of list *userTable* is shown 0.

**SOLVED** : Adding empty constructor of the model class did the trick.

Comment: love u bro :* .....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SugarORM: SugarRecord.count returns 4 but SugarRecord.listAll returns empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521271/sugarorm-sugarrecord-count-returns-4-but-sugarrecord-listall-returns-empty-list)

Comment: You should post the "SOLVED" as an answer...

Comment: Why really?If it knows the count how can't it return it without empty constructor

Answer (score 2):

With SugarORM, all model classes need an empty constructor or they cannot be used.

`UserTableSugar() {}` will do the job!